# How to Get The Value Of UI in For Mat of Thousands-Separator

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhyjaoL/) and let me know how I can get the `value` of slider in format of Thousands-Separator like `5,000` and all values on slide

```
<div id="slider1"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider1-value"></span></p>
$("#slider1").slider(
{
            value:5000,
            min: 250000,
            max: 8000000,
            step: 50,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider1-value" ).html( ui.value );
            }
}
);

$( "#slider1-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jquery-Price-Format](https://github.com/flaviosilveira/Jquery-Price-Format) plugin.
You can format current value like this:

```
              $( "#slider1-value" ).html(ui.value ).priceFormat({
                prefix: '',
                centsSeparator: '.',
                thousandsSeparator: ','

              });
```

See [here](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/rpgWRy) for example.